# In Google App Maker, how do you cause a Multi Select Widget to select all options by default?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

***Background***

Google App Maker has a Multi Select Widget which allows the user to select several options from a list.

[image: Multi Select Widget with 'Suppliers' heading]

***Current State***

By default, all options are unselected and the user must manually select all desired options.

***Desired State***

I would like to programatically cause all options to be selected so that the user can manually deselect all undesired options.

***What I've Tried***

*App Maker Documentation:*

The [Multi Select Widget documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/input-widgets#multi-select) provides information about how to bind options and values, but does not provide an option for pre-selecting these options.

*Javascript onAttach Event and onDataLoad Event:*

I attempted to run Javascript to programatically select the options but think this is where I'm coming undone.

The options in my Multi Select Widget are bound to `@datasources.Suppliers.items..Supplier_Name` and all options are displayed in the widget correctly.

I can successfully hard-code the options to be programatically selected, e.g.:

```
var optionsToBeProgramaticallySelected = ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3"];
widget.values = optionsToBeProgramaticallySelected;
```

... however, I do not want to hard-code the values to be selected because these will change over time. Therefore, I attempted to programatically create an array of all options and use *that* as the list of options to be programatically selected. However, I was not able to successfully return the array for use. The code I used to attempt this is:

```
var listOfAllPossibleOptions = app.datasources.Suppliers.items.concat();
widget.values = listOfAllPossibleOptions;
```

***Question***

How can I cause my Multi Select Widget to select *all* options?

Comment: var listOfAllPossibleOptions = app.datasources.Suppliers.items.concat(); seems like it is creating a string concatenation of the array. What happens if you simply use var listOfAllPossibleOptions = app.datasources.Suppliers.items? Or alternately make that concatenated list and then .split() it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try querying the Suppliers datasource (on the server side), getting the results into an array.

Your client side function (multi select widget is passed on as parameter):

```
function querySuppliers(MultiSelectWidget){
    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(function() {
      alert("Unable to query suppliers");
  })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(result) {//this is the return value from server side
      MultiSelectWidget.values = result;
       })
     .querySuppliers();
}
```

Your server side function:

```
function querySuppliers(){
  var suppliersDS = app.models.Suppliers.newQuery();//new query to datasource
  var suppliers = suppliersDS.run();//run the query
  var returnArray = [];//array to store suppliers
  for (i=0; i<suppliers.length; i++) {//traverse through suppliers to grab names
    returnArray.push(suppliers[i].Supplier_Name);
  }
  return returnArray;
}
```